# Django: two-step RelatedManager

Tags: django, django-custom-manager, django-related-manager

I have three models linked by foreign keys:

```
class One(models.Model):
    ...

class Two(models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(One)

class Three(models.Model):
    two = models.ForeignKey(Two)
```

and I can do:

```
one.two_set.all()
```

to access all related 'Two' instances from a 'One' instance.

How can I build a custom manager to access all 'Three' instances from a 'One' instance?

I need this because I have a framework which builds an HTML table given an instance and one of its managers:

```
create_child_table(instance, manager_name)
```

so, it would be fine if I can have a 'three_set' manager to be used on the instance.

**SOLUTION**
I ended up by adding a ForeignKey from Three to One.
Thanks to your answers that reminded me of the KISS philosophy.

Comment: you want to access both `two` and `three` related instances from `one`?

Comment: I'd like something like 'one.three_set.all()' to get all related Three objects

Comment: any specific reason to use `one.three_set.all()` format?

Comment: Yes, I have a framework which builds an HTML table given an instance and the name of a manager, e.g. `create_child_table(instance, manager_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a manager. This will do it:

```
Three.objects.filter(two__one=one)
```

Comment: Not the solution, but a useful hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). You can use the lower case name of the related model, in your case `two` and `three` eg:

```
one_tow_three = One.objects.all().values('two','two__three')
```